# How can I export and save data in csv format on my local android device from my android application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-file, android-fileprovider

I would like to export and save data locally on my android device in csv format, however, it can only save in my Google Drive or be shared via email now. How do I store it locally as a csv file on my device?

Here is the code where I can save it in my Google Drive.

When I click on the download icon as seen in the image below, the data should be saved in csv format. I want the data to be stored in the 'Files' folder as shown in the images below where the first image shows the "Files" folder icon and the second image shows the inside contents of the "Files" folder.

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ReportAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReportListingActivity.this, ReportDetailsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("flightnumber",reportitems.get(position).getFlightNumber());
            intent.putExtra("departuredate",reportitems.get(position).getDepartureDate());

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadClick(int position) {

            export(); //export it to the csv file

        }

    });


}
```

```
public void export(){
//generate data
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    data.append("Time, Distance");

    for(int i = 0 ; i<5; i++) {
        data.append("\n" + String.valueOf(i) + "," + String.valueOf(i*i));

    }

    try {

        //saving file into device
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("data.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        out.write(data.toString().getBytes());
        out.close();

        //exporting
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        File filelocation = new File(getFilesDir(), "data.csv");
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.myapplication.fileprovider", filelocation);
        Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        fileIntent.setType("text/csv");
        fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data");
        fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent,"Download CSV"));



    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: When I click on the download icon as seen in the screenshot, the data should be save in csv format]

[image: Files folder]
[image: Inside the files folder]

Comment: `Here is the code where I can save it in my Google Drive.` Only if the user chooses that drive you can upload your local file to the drive. The user could as well choose a different app. But... before you launch ACTION_SEND you already saved to file on your device. And you were done at `out.close()`.

Comment: `File filelocation = new File(getFilesDir(), "data.csv");` There is your file.

Comment: if I want to locate the file and open it on my device, where do I find it?

Comment: You have the file location i would say. Have a look at filelocation.getAbsolutePath(). You saved the file in your apps private directory so other apps cannot see it. Further its unclear how and with what you wanna open your file.

Comment: It throws this error while trying to write - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.myapplication.fileprovider/data/data.csv from pid=6997, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: I want to open the file in csv format with a button click on my app

Comment: Well post your code (not in a comment but in a new code block). And if your app opens the file itself you dont need to use your file provider.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated the code and added an image to make it more clear

Comment: I do not see any code that tries to open your file. And i have no idea what that image clears up. You have not explained the symbols of them.

Comment: I am not opening any file, I am just trying to export the contents to a csv file first when I click the download icon as shown in the image and as the code tells in the above code snippet, and while doing that I got the above error - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.myapplication.fileprovider/data/data.csv from pid=6997, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: `public void onDownloadClick(int position) {

            export(); //export it to the csv file

        }` What are you downloading? You are saving data to file and then share the file. Please use better function names.

Comment: @blackapps okay sorry about that, will keep that in mind, will change the name to onSave

Comment: I am just trying to export the contents to a csv file first,` Yes. But your error comes only when you try to share the file. So please make it clear. And you said at certain moment that you wanted to open the file. But you are trying to share the file i would say. All very confusing.

Comment: Take two buttons. One where you save to file and another one where you try to share the file. As now you mix your problems up for us with save, share and open.

Comment: Okay let me make it clearer - the icon as shown just needs to save the file as csv, I do not want to share or open it there. Now when I add this filelocation.getAbsolutePath(), it returns me /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/data.csv. So where do I search for this file on my device now, so I can manually open it?

Comment: You dont stay with your problem and jump from one thing to the other. I already said that it is a private path. And you told full path so you know where your file is exactly. And i have no idea what you mean by manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229042/discussion-between-ian-bell-and-blackapps).

Comment: Now that I have saved the file, I just want to open the file from within my phone so that I can see the file contents. I understand it is stored privately, so if I want to open the file locally on my device, is there a way to do it or not? If there isn't, then we can't do anything about it, If there is a way, I would like to know how it can be done.

Comment: Your app can open the file of course. Your app will open it locally.  For the rest you are not coming to the point. I asked you what you ment with manually and you still did not tell. And you know (as you were told) that other apps have no access. But... you did not tell if you wanted to use another app. Its all so unclear what you want.

Comment: By opening manually I meant -  by going to the "Files" folder on my local device and opening it from there by clicking on it. I do not want to use another app. However, if you consider the default Files folder on a local device/emulator as 'another' app, then yes I want to open it using the Files folder. Is that possible or not?

Comment: I do not want to open the file within the app. I want to save the data in csv format from my app in my "Files" folder of my device, and then go to the Files folder by exiting the app, and open the file there. I hope the whole problem is clear

Comment: I have never seen a Files folder in any Android device. And you saved your file to getFilesDir() which is private to your app.  Further you did not tell which app you wanted to use to open a file from a folder if you do not want to use your app.

Comment: I have updated the question whereby I have attached the "Files" folder as seen on my android emulator. My bad if I saved to getFilesDir() because I want to save it outside of the app locally and access it from the "Files" app as shown. How can I save it outside the app in the "Files" folder? When I can click on Files folder it opens with Downloads title.

Comment: There is no Files folder. I said that before. There is only a Files app. And what you show are Downloads in a Download folder.

Comment: Okay, then please excuse me for the confusion. I didn't understand the difference between Files app and folder. I want to open it from the Files app. How can I do that?

Comment: Then you should not save to getFilesDir() but to a different storage location. A storage location that is reachable for the Files app.

Comment: Okay, and how can I save it to a location that is outside of my app? Say in the Files app under Downloads/Documents folder

Comment: Why are you talking about outside of your app? We never talked about inside of your app! Only about an app private storage location. Files are saved to storage. Not to apps.

Comment: Okay, so if I reiterate here based on what we have discussed how can I store the files to a storage location which is reachable for another app, and thus be able open it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: Okay, thank you ! :) Will check it out! Appreciate your time! :)

Comment: @blackapps How can I specify the 'URI' while saving the csv file? I referred to the above doc, however, I do not know how to specify the initial URI while saving the csv file

Comment: What is the location you wanna save the file to?

Comment: Downloads folder inside my Files app

Comment: Apps do not contain folders. Storages contain folders.

Comment: Okay, I want it in my Downloads folder on my phone

Comment: Use full path of that Download folder instead of path of getFilesDir().

Comment: Okay, I will try doing that! Thank you so much :) I really appreciate your help @blackapps